# Just installed UBUNTU 12.04.3 - XTERM XT Error Can't display

Tags: xterm

I am new, just installed Ubuntu and trying to see the output of commands. I can't open/don't know how to open a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Alt-t usually pops up a terminal.  Or type "terminal" in the Dash search (topmost button on the launcher), and click on the terminal icon to launch, or drag the icon to the launchbar to keep it handy.

Comment: Thanks, when I type in terminal dconte@ubuntu:~$ to a blank line, then when I enter in a command nothing happens or I get rsp_write() failed: Bad File Descriptor